Scale PDF page size _without_ adding white background
I have a PDF containing an A5 page. For reasons, I want to "rescale" that page to be A4-sized - but not by adding margin/padding; I want the actual content scaled. i.e. the opposite of what this question asks for. I'm on a Windows 10 machine. How can I achieve this?
Note: The scaling must not involve rasterization, or any other degradation of quality.

try printing to PDF ... I think that the print dialog has an option to scale the page ... I do not know if the scaling process adds white background

@jsotola: Tried that. It might work, but it depends on the PDF viewer + print driver combination. Mine didn't work - I got the white margins :-(

try changing the margin width to zero

@jsotola: Changing it where?

cpdf.exe -scale-to-fit a4portrait in.pdf -o out.pdf (or a4landscape as appropriate) should do this. Note that this only works since A5 and A4 have the same ratio of width to height. Otherwise, you would see strips of white on two sides.

(Answer due to @johnwhitington)
Use a PDF command-line manipulation tool which supports such (lossess) scaling. One such tool is cpdf, short for "Coherent PDF".

Get the binary distribution from community.coherentpdf.com, or from the GitHub repo releases section. You can also get the source and build if you like.

In the ZIP archive, select the directory relevant to your platform, and decompress the binary any there into anyway on your path.

Assuming your input file is original.pdf and you want to create scaled.pdf , write:
cpdf -scale-to-fit a4portrait original.pdf -o scaled.pdf



Note that if your PDF contains some rasterized images (such as PNG or JPEG) - its resolution on the scaled page will be lower: not because of any degradation by the scaling tool, but because the same number of pixels take up more space. That may appear less pleasing to the viewer.

minor point: "or any other degradation of quality." If you take an image placed in the PDF, double the page size (including the rendering dimensions of the image without resampling it), you have halved the resolution. From a print standpoint this is technically a reduction in quality. Usually called "effective ppi". i.e. 100px square image at 1 inch is 100ppi; same image at 2 inches is 50ppi.

@Yorik: (Minor) point taken.
